# Patching the googleads package for unit testing with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, google-ads-api

I want to test the `ReadAdwords` class method `get_keywords`. The code below works but the test throws the following error: `AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'get'`.

The [source code](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/googleads/adwords.py#L393) says that `GetService()` returns "A googleads.common.GoogleSoapService instance which has the headers and proxy configured for use."

I can't find `def get(` anywhere in the source, not just on the soap service instance that is being returned. What's going on here? Is there a way to patch this whilst still using `autospec=True`?

The equivalent `get` method in the PHP library is [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/v201809/cm/AdGroupCriterionService.php#L182).

The only similar question I have found whilst searching stack overflow is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501583/mocking-googleads-for-unit-tests).

The class:

```
class ReadAdwords:
    def __init__(self, adwords_client):
        self.adwords_client = adwords_client

    def get_keywords(self, selector):
        ad_group_criterion_service = self.adwords_client.GetService(
            "AdGroupCriterionService", version="v201809"
        )

        return ad_group_criterion_service.get(selector)
```

The test:

```
@patch("googleads.common.GoogleSoapService", autospec=True)
@patch("googleads.adwords.AdWordsClient", autospec=True)
def test_get_keywords(mock_Adwords_client, mock_google_soap_service):
    read_adwords = ReadAdwords(mock_Adwords_client)

    mock_Adwords_client.GetService.return_value = mock_google_soap_service

    read_adwords.get_keywords("a string")

    mock_Adwords_client.GetService.assert_called_once()
    mock_google_soap_service.get.assert_called_once()
```